# Why does SXSSF workbook (Apache POI) create larger xlsx sizes than Excel?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, sxssf

I developed a Java class to use the SXSSF workbook to overcome the Java Heap error which is always caused by the XSSF workbook when writing very large spreadsheets. See http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf for the solution.

In short, I use `workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(SXSSFWorkbook.DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE);` instead of `workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();`

This solution works like magic and I am now able to write very large xlsx spreadsheets with a much lower memory footprint.

However, there is one problem which I am stuck. When using the SXSSF workbook, it actually generates a larger xlsx file size compared with Excel itself. For example, 33MB is created by SXSSF while Excel creates 25MB with the same dataset. Why?

I investigated and found the reason:

I changed the .xlsx extension name to .zip so I could open it and view the **\xl\worksheets\sheet1.xml** worksheet file. I discovered inline strings using `t="inlineStr"` are produced by SXSSF while the shared strings table using t="s" (v tag) is produced by Excel. I checked XSSF also creates the shared strings table. Having t="inlineStr" in every cell in an enormous spreadsheet blows up the file size faster.

My question, is it possible to force the SXSSF workbook to generate the `sheet1.xml` file based on the shared strings table (using v tags - t="s") rather than the inline strings (t="inlineStr")? I am hoping this solution would reduce the final file size considerably. Anyone knows?

Comment: The API documentation of `SXSSFWorkbook` states that this is possible using [public SXSSFWorkbook(XSSFWorkbook workbook, int rowAccessWindowSize, boolean compressTmpFiles, boolean useSharedStringsTable)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html#SXSSFWorkbook-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook-int-boolean-boolean-) constructor and set `useSharedStringsTable` `true`. But using inline strings is one of the things which decreases memory usage. It reduces memory usage at the expense of disk space usage. So maybe the heap error occurs again then.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing it out. I realised the preferred choice is not to use the shared strings table to conserve memory. Testing showed the performance decreased noticeably when using the shared strings table. It is a compromise you have to decide, depending on your application.